# detecting mode of gwt designer (design mode or runtime)

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

Is it possible to detect if a ui binder template is being generated in eclipse by the GWT Designer or being generated at runtime mode?

I would like to create a ui to display an data object and thus need to be able to generate one when running in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Beans.isDesignTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Beans.html#isDesignTime%28%29).

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/faq.html and http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/enhanced_compilation.html

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
if(GWT.isProdMode()){... }
```

JavaDoc:

> GWT.isProdMode()
>   Returns true when running in production mode. Returns false when
>   running either in development mode, or when running in a plain JVM.

Regards,
Stefan